# How is the degree of the minimal polynomial related to the degree of a field extension?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

I was reading through some field theory, and was wondering whether the minimal polynomial of a general element in a field extension L/K has degree less than or equal to the degree of the field extension? i.e.

$deg$(m$_{a}$) $\leq$   $[L:K]$    $\forall$ a $\in$ $L$

If it is true, then could anyone give me an idea as to how to prove this please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$d=[L:K]$ is the dimension of $L$ when viewed as a vector space over $K$.

Consider $1,a,a^2,\dots,a^{d}$. This is a list of $d+1$ elements of $L$. Can they be linearly independent over $K$? What does it mean if they aren't?

Comment: well those d+1 elements HAVE to be linearly dependent, since its a d-dimensional vector space, so they obviously cant be linearly independent but I cant quite see how that would mean that the minimal polynomial has to have degree less than d

Comment: Well, the minimal polynomial is degree $\leq d$, not $<d$. And write out what it means for them to be linearly dependent over $K$.

Comment: Ok, well ,let's suppose then that a minimal polynomial exists for $a$ such that its degree is greater than $d$ (say $d+1$), and since the minimal polynomial is a non-zero polynomial, doesn't this show that those vectors ARE in fact linearly dependent, as we would want them to be?

Comment: You are starting in the wrong direction. What does it mean that $1,a,a^2,\dots,a^{d}$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: Well it means that there exists c$_{0}$, c$_{1}$,...,c$_{d}$ , not all zero, such that c$_{0}$(1) + ...+ c$_{d}$(a$^d$) = 0, i am sorry for being an idiot! but I literally cannot see how it progresses from here.

Comment: What can you say about the  $c_i$? What field are they in? @user1314

Comment: And what can you say about the polynomial $p(x)=c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2\cdots c_dx^d$? @user1314

Comment: Ok, so the c$_{i}$ are in L as well as K, so p(x) is in L[X], and therefore it is reducible?
Edit: Actually that doesn't really help, does it.

Comment: Why would you try to use $c_i\in L$? $c_i\in K$ is a stronger condition, and you are seeking a minimal polynomial in $K[x]$. What do we know about $p(x)$? Do we know anything at all about it, other than it is in $K[x]$?

Comment: well it has $a$ as a root, and is irreducible over K[X].

Comment: Why is is irreducible? (It's not.) So it is a polynomial in $K[x]$ of degree $d$ with $a$ as a root. What can you say about the degree of the minimal polynomial?

Comment: I think I finally have it! Suppose we have $a$ $\in$ L. Then since $1$, $a$,...$a^d$ are linearly dependent over K (Its a d-dimensional vector space) we have a non zero polynomial of the above form such that $a$ is it's root. And since the minimal polynomial is a generator of the principal ideal consisting of all polynomials with $a$ as a root, it must divide it, and therefore its degree must be less than or equal to d?

Comment: This has nothing to do with principal ideals. What is the degree of $p$? What does the word "minimal" mean? :)

Comment: well, it means the smallest, so degree of $p$ must always be less than or equal to $d$

Comment: No, $p$ is not the minimal polynomial. You are confusing two thing. $p(x)\in K[x]$ is just a non-zero polynomial of degree at most $d$ which has  $a$ as a root. So the minimal polynomial is a polynomial $q(x)\in K[x]$ of least degree with $q(a)=0$. So, what can we say about the degree of $q$ versus the degree of $p$?

Comment: What I meant was that the degree of the minimal polynomial must be smaller or equal to the degree of p, since the minimal polynomial is of "minimal degree"

Comment: Right, so you are done - $deg(m_a)\leq \deg(p)\leq d$.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much for being very patient and tolerating my stupidity. On a side note, for the above question, can't we just do exactly the same process but for d+2 vectors instead and get that degree of the minimal polynomial is less than or equal to d+1?
Edit: Actually, just realised that even if we do get that the degree of the minimal polynomial is less than d+1(which is true), since we have already proved that the degree of the minimal polynomial is less than or equal to d, there is no way for the degree to be d+1.  Thank you once again!